# Notice, array to string conversion

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an issue in my codeigniter script, I can't seem to figure out what the issue is, can anyone possibly help.

```
$a =  '<a href="' . $item['href'] . '" class="' . $aClass . '">' . $item['text'] . '</a>';
```

Error:
Severity: Notice

Message: Array to string conversion

Filename: libraries/Menu.php

Line Number: 193

*Copied from your comment*

This is what the Var_dump produces:

```
Severity: Notice Message: Array to string conversion Filename: libraries/Menu.php Line Number: 193
```

And this is the var_dump of $item

```
array (size=3) 
  'href' => string '/for-sale/' (length=10) 
  'text' => array (size=0) empty 
  'children' => null
```

Comment: What's the error you're getting? seems fine to me at first glance.

Comment: Edited the question, and the script on line 193 is the one in the question

Comment: Can you do a `var_dump($item)` and see if there's something strange?

Comment: array to string conversion mean that one the parameters in the echo line is array

Comment: use `is_array` to all of the output to know which one is the array

Comment: So its not a problem? And theres nothing unusual in the var_dump from what I can see.

Comment: they are all strings in your dump?  is this running on the same set of data as when you saw the error?

Comment: `$item['href']` and `$item['text']` both show up as being a `string`? What about `$aClass` could this be an array?

Comment: Yep, haven't changed the data at all. This is what the Var_dump produces:
`Severity: Notice

Message: Array to string conversion

Filename: libraries/Menu.php

Line Number: 193

array (size=3)
  'href' => string '/for-sale/' (length=10)
  'text' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  'children' => null`

Comment: Does it look like I'm that user?!...

Comment: @CasperRound can you please use `is_array` with the parameters and show us the result ?

Comment: @CasperRound Who said you were that user? It's a duplicate question either way.

Comment: It's not a duplicate question - if it where then it would have the same code...

Comment: @robert is_array doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: i wrote the full code in answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `text` variable is an array, this is why it's showing your error.

you could try to add it using : `implode(' ', $item['text'])`
or change the `$item['text']` to turn it into a string.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the below, you will not get this array to string errors

```
<?php
        $aClass = 'mylinks';
        $items = array(
                    array(
                        'href'=>'http://test.com',
                        'text'=>'Test',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'href'=>'http://google.com',
                        'text'=>'Google',
                    ),
                  );
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $a =  '<a href="' . $item['href'] . '" class="' . $aClass . '">' . $item['text'] . '</a>';
            echo $a.'<br/>';
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

please run this code and show us the result to help you

```
echo '$item[\'href\'] is '.(is_array($item['href'])?'array':'string').'<br/>';
echo '$aClass is '.(is_array($aClass)?'array':'string').'<br/>';
echo '$item[\'text\'] is '.(is_array($item['text'])?'array':'string').'<br/>';
```

Comment: `$item['href'] is string
$aClass is string
$item['text'] is string
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Array to string conversion

Filename: libraries/Menu.php

Line Number: 193

$item['href'] is string
$aClass is string
$item['text'] is array`

Comment: so as i see `$item['text'] is array` mean that the error here

Comment: try this code now `print_r($item['text']);` and give me the result

Comment: there are something wrong with your code that make the `$item['text']` empty array in the next time you use it so do you use `$item['text']=array()` or `$item['text']=[]`

Answer (score 0):

This is the relevant item from your var_dump

```
'text' => array (size=0) empty
```

The 'text' occurance is itself an array.

So fix the way you create the array or how you use it.